# When is the iso-comma category $F \wr G $ a reflective subcategory of the comma category $F \downarrow G$?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $F \wr G$ be the iso-comma category. This is basically the same construction as the comma category $F \downarrow G$ except that we require the morphism $F(x) \to G(y)$ to be an isomorphism instead. Observe that $F \wr G$ is a full subcategory of $F \downarrow G$, my question is: under what conditions does the inclusion admit a left (or possibly right) adjoint? i.e. when is $F \wr G$ a (co)reflective subcategory of $F \downarrow G$?

I'm looking for any references which consider this question as well.

---

**Edit**: 4 years later and rereading this question, I've noticed that perhaps it is a bit dry. I will try to add some context to why I was thinking about it in the first place.

If we think of an $\Omega$-prespectrum as a sequence of pointed spaces together with pointed maps between them, then you can see that the category of $\Omega$-prespectra is a comma category where the objects of the source of $F$ and $G$ are sequences of pointed spaces and the $G$ functor shifts the indexing of a pointed space by 1. Then the triple in the comma category consists of a sequence of morphisms.

In the same way, such an iso-comma category would require a pointed isomorphism between the spaces. This would then be the category of $\Omega$-spectra. Obviously, this is a bit nonsense since we should be asking for weak-homotopy equivalences rather than isomorphisms, but pretend, even if it is not true, that such a category is possible. (My intuition being that it will hold in some higher setup).

There is an $\Omega$-spectrification functor from prespectra to spectra, therefore the inclusion functor has a left adjoint, using the universal property of spectrification.

Hence, in this poorly constructed example, I have reason to believe that something about the category of spectra allows for these inclusion maps to be adjoint.

Spectra are obviously a very special category, where all limits and colimits exist, and furthermore they are equivalent over the same shapes.

My question can therefore be rephrased as follows: Is there a general reason for this phenomenon?

Comment: It seems to me that such an adjoint acts on objects of $(F/G)$ yielding an isomorphism $Fx\cong Gy$ between the same objects; this is because a natural requesto on it is that it commutes with the forgetful functors to the domains of $F,G$. Now, I wonder what is a natural choice for such an isomorphism between the same objects...

Comment: If we put the additional restriction that @Fosco suggested and also the restriction that it acts in the same way on morphisms, then the adjoint will exist only in trivial cases when $F \wr G$ coincides with $F \downarrow G$.

Comment: If the domains of $F$ and $G$ are locally presentable, their codomain is accessible, and $F$ and $G$ preserve colimits, then both $F \wr G$ and $F \downarrow G$ are locally presentable and $F \wr G$ is closed under colimits in $F \downarrow G$. It follows that it is a coreflective subcategory.

Comment: Cool, so it is too restrictive to ask that the adjoint is an adjunction in ${\sf Cat}/(A\times B)$. I guess the existence follows from AFT or Freyd-Kelly (which is still AFT :D ); is there any chance to get a grip on how the adjoint is defined in this case? It looks like a controlled way of localizing (in the sense of homotopy categories) $(F\downarrow G)$.